# Martial arts and hinduism

Tags: scripture, kshatriya, war

[Indian Martial Arts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_martial_arts) is one of the most ancient martial art technique. Since a kshatriya's duty involves learning martial arts and dictates him to learn Martial Arts for the same purpose. So with this context are there any hindu scriptures (Preferably Ramayana/Mahabharat as they have Kshatriya centered stories) that have information on  Ancient Martial Arts and Techniques involved, which were used in Epic wars.

Is there any other Scripture which gives detailed information on ancient Indian (mostly extinct) martial arts? What was reference book/manual to learn Martial arts and war techniques which ancient fighters used.

What is the full list of arts a warrior should learn.

Comment: I have heard martial arts otiginated as Lord Shiva to Lord Parashuram and Bodhidharman  to China....

Comment: Some believe that the modern martial art forms originated from the Tamil martial art Kalaripayattu

Comment: @moonstar2001 Yeah I am talking about vidyas , but I don't need magical astra vidya. The mantras of Atharvana veda have metaphysical connection.